# InvokeHttp processor is gets stuck in processing state, and does not fail even after specified timeout causing flow files to pile up in queue above

Tags: java, devops, etl, apache-nifi

I'm using an invokeHttp processor in nifi to make an api call to fetch some data, but from past few days this processor gets stuck with a thread showing on top in processing state. So I have to manually stop and terminate the processor and start again so that the data in queue above starts processing.  After this manual terminate an restart it works fine for some time just to get stuck after sometime. I have added timeout in the processor but this does not help as no failure is generated event after the timeout.

[I have stopped the invoke https manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyxC4.png)

This issue has recently occurred and earlier the same flow was working correctly, and i have tried changing the timeout the invokeHttp processor but not getting any failure when the processor is stuck for long period of time.